# How to remove items from nested immutable collections

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary that contains an array of items (NSDictionary type).  I need to remove one particular key (and its associated object) stored in each item.  What's the best way to go about this?

Example structure:

```
   NSDictionary *dict = @{ 
       @"v" : @[ 
          @{ @"key1": @"abc", @"key2" : @"def" },
          @{ @"key1": @"ghi", @"key2" : @"jkl" }, ...
        ]
    };
```

I want to eliminate all key1 from the nested dictionary element:

```
@{ 
   @"v" : @[ 
      @{ @"key2" : @"def" },
      @{ @"key2" : @"jkl" }, ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: You mean you have a Dictionary, where you have array objects, and each array has more dictionaries?

Comment: What makes your array a dictionary?

Comment: @Merlevede yes you are right.

Comment: Simon is right, in the sense that your inner dictionaries are not mutable. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Immutable to start, but I can always create an NSMutableDictionary and initialize it with this dictionary.

Comment: Updated my answer with code snippet. You just want to create NSMutabledictionary for each dictionary for removing the key/object pair, and then replace the corresponding entry in the array.

Comment: And `dict` should be NSMutableDictionary, right?

Comment: This question is [being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222162).

Comment: @Emracool Not a duplicate, compare accepted answer with your post.

Comment: Ah, so it would seem. My apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [@{
                       @"v" : @[
                               @{ @"key1": @"abc", @"key2" : @"def" },
                               @{ @"key1": @"ghi", @"key2" : @"jkl" }
                               ]
                       } mutableCopy];

NSArray *oldArray = [dict objectForKey:@"v"];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[oldArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [dictionary mutableCopy];
    [mutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:@"key1"];
    [newArray addObject:mutableDictionary];
}];
[dict setObject:newArray forKey:@"v"];
```

Comment: why the `__block` when declaring `newArray`?

Comment: @Sebastian Normally blocks `copy` the variables inside them, so changes to the variables aren't available outside the block.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW6

Comment: (You wouldn't need `__block` if you used a simple for loop instead of `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`.)

Comment: But you're not changing the variable. (the variable being the pointer, not the object pointed to)

Comment: @AaronBrager There is no need to use __block with the array, I have confirmed.

Comment: Right.  Updated to remove `__block`.

Answer (score 0):

For your main dictionary you can enumerate your objects using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` and for the arrays you can use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`

```
[self.myDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray *array = (NSArray *)obj;
    [arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj2, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {
         NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictonary *)obj2;
         // remove item from dict
    }];
}];
```

I didn't test it but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score -1):

Enumerate through the `NSArray` and call `[dict removeObjectForKey:@"key1"]`for each dictionary.

**Edit:**
If they are NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary, do the following:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[mutableDict setDictionary:originalDict];
[mutableDict removeObjectForKey:@"key1"];
NSDictionary *newDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:mutableDict];
```

Use `newDict` however you'd like, probably replace the original one in NSArray

**Edit again with entire solution:**

```
NSArray *a = [outerDict objectForKey:@"v"];
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary d in a) {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [mutableDict setDictionary:d];
    [mutableDict removeObjectForKey:@"key1"];
    NSDictionary *newDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:mutableDict];
    [newArray addObject:newDict];
}
[outerDict setObject:newArray ForKey:@"v"];
```

Comment: How can you call removeObjectForKey when NSArray is storing NSDictionary?

Comment: If they are `NSDictionary`s then copy them into NSMutableDictionary then call remove. I'm afraid there is no quick and efficient way to do it as NSDictionary is immutable.

Comment: I don't think your solution will work because key1 is in dictionary inside the array.

Comment: I just didn't write out the entire solution. My code would fit in the for loop for the array, so you already have each of the inner dictionaries.

Comment: Your solution won't work.  If this question is trivial, I would not ask it here.

Comment: You keep saying it won't work but don't explain why. If you know what you're talking about, you'd realize most of the proposed answers are effectively equivalent.

Comment: Because I am not a newbie, I can clearly see your solution won't work before you edited it.  And I did explain why it won't but I can't keep explaining you know?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the inner dictionaries are actually mutable (as your stated) and not inline, you want something like this:

```
NSString *removeKey = @"key1";
for (NSArray *array in [outerDict allValues])
{
    for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in arrayOfDicts)
    {
        [dict removeObjectForKey:removeKey];
    }
}
```

... but you still need to have the inner dictionaries mutable. If you want to set it up inline, and have them be mutable, this will work:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"v" : @[
                               [@{ @"key1": @"abc", @"key2" : @"def" } mutableCopy],
                               [@{ @"key1": @"ghi", @"key2" : @"jkl" } mutableCopy]
                               ]
                       };
```

Comment: You don't need a key for the outermost.  This is a dictionary literal.